# Rewrite Rule not working in .htaccess file Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I've created a .htaccess file for my site running on my own server, Apache Ubuntu 22.04, where everything works fine except for Rewrite Rule. I definitely have mod_rewrite turned on as when I created a php file with phpinfo(); it appears in the loaded modules. I have also gone into the apache.conf and sites-enabled conf files and turned AllowOverride to All.

the Redirect Rule works completely fine with no issue yet whenever I try to use the Rewrite Rule it never seems to work.

This code works:

```
Redirect /foobar/ https://example.com
```

However this code doesn't:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foobar/$ https://example.com/ [R]
```

This is what I have changed in my apache2.conf file

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Would anyone know why this could be, as nothing I've tried works and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure that you only want to redirect the exact path `/foobar/`? And not things like `/foobar/baz` too? Note that a `Redirect` and a `RewriteRule` work different in that.